# Including root node in JSON Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need to include the top level node in my JSON response in order for the already deployed mobile app to work. My models are Language and Posts where Posts belongs_to Language. The response the app needs is this:

```
{
  "english": {
  "posts": [
  {
    "title": "title",
    "content": "content"
  },
```

My Language controller code looks like this:

```
@posts = @language.posts
render :json => { :posts => @posts.as_json
```

Just need to get the Language in the JSON one level above it. Isn't there a config in environment or deploy.rb that takes care of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a JSON template? Then you can customize it however you want.

For example, in your controller:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def show
  @language = ...
  @posts = ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json
  end
end
```

Then in your views,

```
/* app/views/posts/show.json.erb */
{
  "<%= @language =>": {
    "posts": <%= @posts.to_json.html_safe =>
  }
}
```

I am not sure if nesting JSON this way would cause any syntax issues. Alternatively, you could also build the hash and then call `to_json`. For example,

```
def show
  @language = ...
  @posts = ...
  render json: { @language => @posts }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`@language.as_json(:include => :posts)` would produce what you want, I believe.

EDIT:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_json(opts = {})
    {self.name => self.posts}.to_json(opts)
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: That renders:

    {"language":{"created_at":"2013-05-    25T19:36:50Z","id":1,"name":"english","updated_at":"2013-05-    25T19:36:50Z","posts":[{"title":"title"}]}}

If English is ID=1 then in launguage/1.json I need to see English at the top node like in original post.

Comment: I edited my answer.  That should produce the output if yuo just call `@language.to_json`

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to include root in all of your JSON responses then you can head straight to `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`

There you will see / or if not present you can add

```
# To enable root element in JSON for ActiveRecord objects.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
 self.include_root_in_json = true
end
```

**OR**

If this is not sufficient and you want to customize your JSON data further, just reach out for [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). You will have your custom JSON response within a minute and you're not limited to using them only in the view / render.